# iText 'java.io.IOException The document has no pages' while copying pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to copy a pdf from a byte array and stamp each page with a pdf that has a single page. Everytime I try to copy a pdf and stamp each page I get the exception iText 'java.io.IOException The document has no pages'

Here is my code:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream AddPageTemplate(ByteArrayOutputStream baos){    
    Document document = getDocument();
    ByteArrayOutputStream copyWithTemplateAdded = new   ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, copyWithTemplateAdded);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, copyWithTemplateAdded);
        PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(PAGE_TEMPLATE.getInputStream());
        PdfImportedPage templatePage = writer.getImportedPage(templateReader, 1);

        document.open();
        baos.flush();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
        int n1 = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n1; ++i) {
            page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
            stamp.getUnderContent().addTemplate(templatePage, 0, 0);
            stamp.alterContents();
            copy.addPage(page);
        }
        copyWithTemplateAdded.close();
        reader.close();
        copy.close();
        templateReader.close();
        document.close();
    }
    catch(DocumentException p){
        //todo log error
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //todo log error
    }
    return copyWithTemplateAdded;
}
```

Any help resolveing this issue would be great. I am using             itextpdf 5.3.4

Comment: A full stack trace, and a comment in the source showing which line gives you the error, will make the problem a little clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making many different mistakes in a very short code snippet.

One mistake is causing the error: you create `copyWithTemplateAdded` as a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and you use that same `OutputStream` for two writers:

```
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, copyWithTemplateAdded);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, copyWithTemplateAdded);
```

This can never work:

- `PdfCopy` will write bytes to the `OutputStream` with the purpose to copy *existing PDFs* to a new PDF.
- `PdfWriter` will write byte to the *same* `OutputStream` with the purpose to create a *new PDF from scratch*.

The result will be a completely corrupt PDF because:

1. You are mixing `PdfWriter` with `PdfCopy` who are both writing to the same `OutputStream` (think of Jeff Goldblum in [The Fly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091064) to get an idea of what to expect).
2. You obtain the imported page from the `PdfWriter` (meaning that all the references needed will be stored in the `writer` object), but you use the imported page in the `PdfCopy` instance (but `copy` doesn't have any references to the resources needed for that page).

The `IOException` is caused by the fact that the `writer` object is closed (upon `document.close()`) and no content has been added: all content was added to the `copy` object.

Another mistake: you close your `copy` instance before closing the `document`.

But the biggest mistake is that you're using `PdfCopy` (and `PdfWriter`) for something that should probably be done with `PdfStamper`.

Where did you get the inspiration for your code? Could you do me a favor and download [Chapter 6 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/3c9ca46-76da-4de2-8972-b82efbe0bf88/samplechapter6.pdf) and take a look at the [StampStationery](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#266-stampstationery.java) example?

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String stationery, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Create readers
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfReader s_reader = new PdfReader(stationery);
    // Create the stamper
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // Add the stationery to each page
    PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(s_reader, 1);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfContentByte background;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        background = stamper.getUnderContent(i);
        background.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
    // CLose the stamper
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    s_reader.close();
}
```

In this example, we have an existing PDF file (its path is `src`) and a template that we want to add as the background for every page (the path of the template is `stationery`). We create a `PdfStamper` object that will create a new file based on the existing PDF document (the path of the new file will be `dest`).

We load the first page of the template into a `PdfImportedPage` (the `page` object). We loop over every page and we add that `page` in the background. This code comes straight from the documentation and is much easier to understand than what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I am new to iText. I have been given work to do iText related work, but I have not used iText before :-(. I saw the code on some website. Again, Thanks.

Comment: What website would that be, so that people can be warned against me it?